# Why is a variable declared when it appears in "if false"?

Tags: ruby, variables

I'm finding it difficult to understand how the following variable is being set to `nil`, while it seems that it isn't assigned anywhere.

I have tried this in `ruby 2.1.2` and in `ruby 1.8.7`. Both yield the same results.

How is this happening?

```
irb(main):002:0> foo
  NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object

irb(main):003:0> if false
  irb(main):004:1> foo = 1
irb(main):005:1> end

irb(main):006:0> foo
=> nil
```

Comment: (The variable is *not* "assigned" a value, it is however introduced as a local variable - nil is merely the default value, as a variable must evaluate to *a* value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby handles assignments at the parser level. From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods):

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the
>   assignment, not when the assignment occurs:
>
> ```
> a = 0 if false # does not assign to a
>
> p local_variables # prints [:a]
>
> p a # prints nil
> ```

Comment: "Parser encounters the assignment" is a bit vague; consider `def x(t); return y if t; y = "hello world"; end; x(true)` which throws a NameError. Yet the parser "encountered" the entire method body before `x` was invoked.