# Undefined local variable based on syntax in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In the following Ruby code,

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
x = true
y = x and z = y
puts "z: #{z}"
```

It will output `z: true`, as expected.

But in the following one, which I expect to have the same behavior:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
x = true
z = y if y = x
puts "z: #{z}"
```

It results in

> undefined local variable or method 'y' for main:Object (NameError)

Why is that?

I understood I am doing an assignment, and implicitly check for the assignment value to determine whether to run `z = y`. I also understood that if I add declaration of y, `y = nil`, right after the `x = 5` line, it will pass and run as expected.

But isn't it correct to expect that the language should evaluate the `if` part first and then its content, and second chunk of code to behave the same as the first chunk of code?

Comment: That’s a really good question, given that `z = 2 if y = x` works fine, and `z = w if false` does too…

Comment: This is one those stupid areas with Ruby. There is some ill-defined clause which amounts to "if the parser encounters the assignment" (meaning the assignment does *not* have to be executed to create a local binding) .. except it breaks down when in cases like this, and several others. Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783428/why-is-a-variable-declared-when-it-appears-in-if-false

Comment: I'm not a Ruby expert, but this seems like a bug in the parser.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach It's not a "bug". It's "expected behavior", even if not really .. expected.

Comment: @user2864740, agreed. It's effectively equivalent to `if y = x; z = y; end` to the programmer but produces a different result. While the example may be contrived, it's a definite gotcha.

Comment: Thank you all. I am learning something from you guys.

Comment: I assume the same gremlins that are responsible for bare `x=x` not being a `NameError` have their claws in this one.

Comment: @roippi `x=x` is not an error because the assignment `x =` precedes the call `x`.

Comment: @user2864740: Come on, we're allowed to like Ruby and call its stupid things bugs at the same time.

Comment: @muistooshort Maybe a "design shortcoming" or "quirky non-formalized behavior"? :D

Comment: Rubinius does the right thing. MRI and JRuby raise NameError. I didn't test any other implementations. YMMV.

Comment: @sawa Come on. No one expects `x = x` to assign nil to *x*; it *should* raise NameError with a sane parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

This is actually interpreter-specific. The problem shows up in MRI Ruby 2.1.2 and JRuby 1.7.13, but works as expected in [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/). For example, with Rubinius 2.2.10:

```
x = true
z = y if y = x
#=> true
```

In MRI, a little exploration with [Ripper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) shows that Ruby treats the post-condition differently even though the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) assignments are similar. It actually uses different tokens for post-conditions when building the AST, and this appears to have an effect on the evaluation order of assignment expressions. Whether or not this should be the case, or whether it can be fixed, is a question for the [Ruby Core Team](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/ruby-core/).

### Why It Works with a Logical And

```
x = true
y = x and z = y
```

This succeeds because it's really two assignments in sequence, because `true` is assigned to *x* and therefore evaluates as truthy. Since the first expression is truthy, the next expression connected by the logical *and* is also evaluated and likewise evaluates as truthy.

```
y = x
#=> true

z = y
#=> true
```

In other words, *x* is assigned the value `true`, and then *z* is also assigned the value `true`. At no point is the right-hand side of either assignment undefined.

### Why It Fails with a Post-Condition

```
x = true
z = y if y = x
```

In this case, the post-condition is actually evaluated first. You can see this by looking at the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree):

```
require 'pp'
require 'ripper'

x = true

pp Ripper.sexp 'z = y if y = x'
[:program,
 [[:if_mod,
   [:assign,
    [:var_field, [:@ident, "y", [1, 9]]],
    [:vcall, [:@ident, "x", [1, 13]]]],
   [:assign,
    [:var_field, [:@ident, "z", [1, 0]]],
    [:vcall, [:@ident, "y", [1, 4]]]]]]]
```

Unlike your first example, where *y* was assigned `true` in the first expression, and therefore resolved to `true` in the second expression before being assigned to *z*, in this case *y* is evaluated while still undefined. This raises a [NameError](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/NameError.html).

Of course, one could legitimately argue that both expressions contain assignments, and that *y* wouldn't really be undefined if Ruby's parser evaluated `y = x` first as it does with a normal if statement (see AST below). This is probably just a quirk of post-condition if statements and the way Ruby handles the :if_mod token.

### Succeed With :if Instead of :if_mod Tokens

If you reverse the logic and use a normal if statement, it works fine:

```
x = true
if y = x
  z = y
end
#=> true
```

Looking at Ripper yields the following AST:

```
require 'pp'
require 'ripper'

x = true

pp Ripper.sexp 'if y = x; z = y; end'
[:program,
 [[:if,
   [:assign,
    [:var_field, [:@ident, "y", [1, 3]]],
    [:vcall, [:@ident, "x", [1, 7]]]],
   [[:assign,
     [:var_field, [:@ident, "z", [1, 10]]],
     [:var_ref, [:@ident, "y", [1, 14]]]]],
   nil]]]
```

Note that the only real difference is that the example that raises NameError uses :if_mod, while the version that succeeds uses :if. It certainly seems like the post-condition is the cause of the bug, quirk, or misfeature that you're seeing.

### What to Do About It

There may be a good technical reason for this parsing behavior, or there may not. I'm not qualified to judge. However, if it looks like a bug to you, and you're motivated to do something about it, the best thing to do would be to check the [Ruby Issue Tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/) to see if it's already been reported. If not, maybe it's time someone brought it up formally.

Comment: Rubinius uses :if instead of :if_mod in its post-condition AST: `require 'pp'; require 'parser/current'; pp Parser::CurrentRuby.parse 'z = y if y = x'`.

Comment: Good details .. and good job staying out of the fray. I think I now finally have a link-to question for when this comes up again.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Rubinius.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Why ? As condition of inline `if` is processed first, it does make sense parser should handle it similar.

Comment: Related [discussion on Twitter](https://twitter.com/tom_enebo/status/510901060932628480) that explains this as an LALR descent issue with the :if_mod token.